# FirebaseError: Firebase. No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: firebase, react-native

i try to make simple CRUD app froem react native with fire base but i keep getting this error when connecting firebase with app in register view

the function is to register a new user to database in firebase

The error

[image: The error i keep getting]

My register view.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text,TextInput, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import Waiter_login from '../../../components/molecules/Waiter_login/';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

class Register extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.dbRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
        this.state = {
          email: '',
          username: '',
          password: '',
          isLoading: false
        };
      }

      inputValueUpdate = (val, prop) => {
        const state = this.state;
        state[prop] = val;
        this.setState(state);
      }

      storeUser() {
        if(this.state.username === ''){
         alert('Isi username kamu!')
        } else {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: true,
          });      
          this.dbRef.add({
            email: this.state.email,
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password,
          }).then((res) => {
            this.setState({
              email: '',
              username: '',
              password: '',
              isLoading: false,
            });
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error("Error found: ", err);
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
            });
          });
        }
      }


    render(){
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Waiter_login title='Please Register Here' img={require('../../../assets/register-fam.png')} />
                <View style={{ marginLeft:50,marginRight:50,textAlign: 'center', marginVertical: 5}}>
                <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={{ marginTop:10, height: 40, width: 300,paddingLeft:15, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius:25}} value={this.state.username} /*onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}*/onChangeText={(val) => this.inputValueUpdate(val, 'username')} />
                <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={{ marginTop:10, height: 40, width: 300,paddingLeft:15, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius:25}} onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}/>       
                <TextInput placeholder="Phone" style={{ marginTop:10, height: 40, width: 300,paddingLeft:15, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius:25}} onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}/>
                <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={{ marginTop:10, height: 40, width: 300,paddingLeft:15, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius:25}} onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}/>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:'#432f96', borderRadius:15,marginTop:20,paddingBottom:7,paddingTop:7}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:22,fontWeight: 'bold', color:'white',textAlign:'center'}} onPress=/*{() => navigate('Login')}*/{() => this.storeUser()} >Register</Text>
                </View>
                </View>
                {/* <View style={{backgroundColor:'#ffff',marginTop:20,marginLeft:50,marginRight:50}}>
                <Image style={{height:67,width:310}} source={require('./src/assets/login_google.png')} />
                </View> */}
            </View>
            <View style={{height:40,backgroundColor:'#ededed'}}>
                <View style={{alignSelf:'center',marginTop:5}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:12, color:'grey'}}>made with love BudakBandung</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Register;
```

My firebase.js

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig={
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCHTSbVaLFiIvb7QOfzQEdcPxCPCt_5gA4",
    authDomain: "pesendulu-9dd4f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pesendulu-9dd4f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pesendulu-9dd4f",
    storageBucket: "pesendulu-9dd4f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "733125666943",
    appId: "1:733125666943:web:5980721527735d9235b74a",
    measurementId: "G-3TE04D9S77"

};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
 };
firebase.firestore().settings(settings);

export default firebase;
```

what is the problem and what should i do to make it work ? thanks before

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) { firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);}
```

**use this code,this code will fix your issue**